# Doubt in change of basis matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A=\{(1,0,5) (4, 5,5)(1,1,4)\}; B= \{(1,3,2)(-2,-1,1)(1,2,3) \}$. To find change of basis matrix.

$\boxed{ M_{A\to B} = M_{A\to e}M_{e\to B} }  ---(1)\\= \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 4 & 1 \\
0 & 5 & 1 \\
5 &  5 & 4
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin {pmatrix} 
1 & -2 & 1 \\
3 & -1 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & 3
\end {pmatrix} = \boxed {\begin {pmatrix} 
-2 & -2 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
3 & 4 & 2
\end {pmatrix} } -----(2)$

**Is equation (1) correct??? or it is $M_{A \to B} = M_{e \to B} M_{A \to e}$ as given in solution part of LINK:- [How to construct change of basis matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628061/how-to-construct-change-of-basis-matrix) (I am confused here pls correct me if i am wrong...)**

To reconfirm i did it in following way:-

to find coordinates of B interms of A

$(1,3,2)= a(1,0,5)+b(4,5,5)+c(1,1,4)=(a+4b+c,5b+c,5a+5b+4c)=[-2,0,3]_B$

Similarly $(-2,-1,4) \sim [-2,-1,4]_B \\ (1,2,3) \sim [-1,0,2]_B$

THis boils down to same above matrix by (2)
[image]

Comment: There is also a typo, in your hypotesis it should be $M_{A\to B} = M_{e\to A}M_{B\to e}$ but how explained $M_{e\to A}M_{B\to e}=M_{B\to A}$.

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "change of basis matrix"? Because there is closely related "change of coordinate matrix", which is precisely the inverse of that. Maybe the confusion is there.

Comment: @A.Γ.   Sir  i did not go deep. I am at linear transformations part of linear algebra. Change of basis matrix or change of coordinate matrix not same? pls elaborate...
Change of basis matrix -- $[v]_B = Q^{-1}_{A \to B} [v]_A$

Comment: Your first way looks ok to me, the second is unclear, how did you get those matrices in "matrix method"?

Comment: Got it. I misundersttod change of basis matrix. Re-read textbook again. Pls see my last below comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need

$$M_{A\to B} = M_{e\to B}M_{A\to e}$$

that is

$$\begin {pmatrix} 
1 & -2 & 1 \\
3 & -1 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & 3
\end {pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 4 & 1 \\
0 & 5 & 1 \\
5 &  5 & 4
\end{pmatrix} $$

indeed the first matrix takes a vector in basis $A$ to the standard basis and the second takes a vector in the standard basis to the basis $B$, therefore the product matrix takes a vector from basis $A$ to basis $B$.

Comment: can u pls have a look at part 2 or the other way i did to find change of basis matrix. 

To find change of basis matrix i followed - 

output basis = express in terms of input basis

Comment: @anirudhb The matrix M you have found with tour method changes basis from B to A, indeed we have $M(1,0,0)=(-2,0,3)$ which are the components of $(1,3,2)$ in the basis $A$.

Comment: I understood matrix method. Actually i am bit confused about other way. For ex., @gimusi take $M_{e \to A}. \\$$ (1,0,5) = 1e_1+0e_2+5e_3 \\ $... like that i will express output basis vector interms of input basis vector. But i find using same way, output basis B vector = interms of input basis A vectors linear comination, i am gettting $M^{-1}$. Pls clarify.

Comment: $M_{e \to A} \cdot (1,0,5)$ simply gives the components for $(1,0,5)$ in the basis $A$, I don't understand your doubts on that. Please explain better.

Comment: Sir i uploaded my worked out image. Pls have a look

Comment: Also by your method you obtain a matrix which takes a vector in basis B and gives its components in basis A, thus $M_{B\to A}$ according to matrix method.

Comment: Pls see in uploaded image. I have changed in matrix representation

Comment: what u r saying is correct. I did mistake in change of basis matrix. 1st feew lines in uploaded image - matrix i calculated is from A->standard basis. I mistook it as standard basis --> A. Now all problem got right. Took time to re-read textbook and understand.

Comment: $(1,0,5 ) = a(1,3,2)+b(-2,-1,1)+c(1,2,3) =(a-2b+c, 3a-b+2c,2a+b+3c) \implies [a,b,c] = [-2,0,3]\\ $ Similarly doing it igot $M_{A \to B} = \begin {pmatrix} {-2 & 0 &-1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 3 & 2 &2 } \end{pmatrix}$